# Design patterns that can replace if statements

Tags: java, spring-mvc, design-patterns

Our application is getting complex, it has mainly 3 flow and have to process based on one of the 3 type. Many of these functionalities overlap each other.

So currently code is fully of if-else statements, it is all messed up and not organised. How to make a pattern so that 3 flows are clearly separated from each other but making use of power of re-usability.

Please provide some thoughts, this is a MVC application, where we need to produce and consume web servicees using jaxb technology.

May be you can view the application as a single object as input on which different strategies needs to be implemented based on runtime value.

Comment: Please post a portion (or all) of this spaghetti code so that we may give you real and meaningful responses.

Comment: It depends on logic this code does

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is implementing decision tables to get rid of the if/else statements.

Comment: Depends on your use case dear. A Factory pattern might help or Strategy might help there can be some others as well. Unless you post more details it is difficult to answer but you are on the right path to ask for help.

Comment: This might be better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, since you already have code and want to know how to improve it.

Comment: It totally depends on your logic, one of the design patterns could be as we are not clear what exactly you need is Facad.

Comment: @folkol It maybe could, except that... there's no code here. That is a quite important detail for Code Review, as mentioned in [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Yes, Simon. He would have to paste the code in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loong time I find opensource rule engine frameworks like "**drools**" is a great alternative to fit my requirement.

Comment: Can you provide any link ? did you implement same way or you just used **drools** to change runtime behavior ?

Answer (score 8):

You did not specify what your `if-else` statements are doing. Say they `filter`ing depending on some `value`.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to look at [Factory Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html).

This is a clean approach, easy to maintain and produces readable code. Adding or removing a `Filter` is also easy, Just remove the class and remove it from `FilterFactory` hashmap.

Create an Interface : Filter

```
 public interface Filter {
    void Filter();
 }
```

Create a Factory which returns correct Filter according to your `value`. Instead of your `if-else` now you can just use the following :

```
  Filter filter = FilterFactory.getFilter(value);
  filter.filter();
```

One common way to write FilterFactory is using a `HashMap` inside it.

```
public class FilterFactory{
   static HashMap<Integer, Filter> filterMap;
   static{
       filterMap = new HashMap<>();
       filterMap.put(0,new Filter0());
       ...
   }
   // this function will change depending on your needs
   public Filter getFilter(int value){
       return filterMap.get(value);
   }

}
```

Create your three(in your case) Filters like this: (With meaningful names though)

```
public class Filter0 implements Filter {

    public void filter(){
      //do something
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** As you want to reuse some methods, create a `FilterUtility` class and make all your filters extend this class so that you can use all the functions without rewriting them.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is very broad and almost impossible to answer without some description or overview of the structure of your application. However, I've been in a similar situation and this is the approach I took:

**Replace conditions with Polymorphism where possible**

> it has mainly 3 flow and have to process based on this one of the 3
>   type. Many of these functionalities overlap each other.

You say your project has 3 main flows and that much of the code overlaps each other. This sounds to me like a strategy pattern:

You declare an interface that defines the tasks performed by a Flow.

```
public interface Flow{
   public Data getData();
   public Error validateData();
   public void saveData();
   public Error gotoNextStep();
}
```

You create an abstract class that provides implementation that is common to all 3 flows. (methods in this abstract class don't have to be final, but you definitely want to consider it carefully.)

```
public abstract class AbstractFlow{

   private FlowManager flowManager

   public AbstractFlow(FlowManager fm){
    flowManager = fm;
   }

   public final void saveData(){
       Data data = getData();
       saveDataAsXMl(data);
   }

   public final Error gotoNextStep(){

      Error error = validateData();
      if(error != null){
         return error;
      }

      saveData();
      fm.gotoNextStep();
      return null;
   }
}
```

Finally, you create 3 concrete classes that extend from the abstract class and define concrete implementation for the given flow.

```
public class BankDetailsFlow extends AbstractFlow{

   public BankDetailsData getData(){
     BankDetailsData data = new BankDetailsData();
     data.setSwiftCode(/*get swift code somehow*/);
     return data;
   }

   public Error validateData(){
      BankDetailsData data = getData();
      return validate(data);
   }

   public void onFormSubmitted(){
      Error error = gotoNextStep();
      if(error != null){
        handleError(error);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets take example, suppose you have model say "Data" [which has some attributes and getters,setters, optional methods].In  context of Mobile application ,in particular Android application there can be two modes Off-line or On-line. If device is connected to network , data is sent to network else stored to local database of device.
In procedural way someone can , define two models as OnlineData,OfflineData and write code as[The code is not exact ,its just like pseudo code ]:

```
if(Connection.isConnected()){
   OnlineData ond=new OnlineData();
   ond.save();//save is called which stores data on server using HTTP.
}
else{
   OfflineData ofd=new Onlinedata();
   ofd.save();//save is called which stores data in local database
}
```

A good approach to implement this is using OOPS principles :

> Program to interface not Implementation

Lets see How to DO THIS.
I am just writing code snippets that will be more effectively represent what I mean.The snippets are as follows:

```
public interface Model {
   long save();//save method 
   //other methods .....
}


public class OnlineData extends Model {
  //attributes  
  public long save(){
    //on-line implementation of save method for Data model
  }
  //implementation of other methods.
}

public class OfflineData extends Model {
  //attributes  
  public long save(){
    //off-line implementation of save method for Data model
  }
  //implementation of other methods.
}
public class ObjectFactory{
   public static Model getDataObject(){
     if(Connection.isConnected())
         return new OnlineData();
     else 
         return new OfflineData();

  }
}
```

and Here is code that your client class should use:

```
public class ClientClass{
    public void someMethod(){
      Model model=ObjectFactory.getDataObject();  
      model.save();// here polymorphism plays role...
   }
}
```

Also this follows:

> Single Responsibility Principle [SRP]

because On-line and Off-line are two different responsibilities which we can be able to integrate in Single save() using if-else statement.