# get instance of sub-classes without if else or reflection or switch-case

Tags: java, polymorphism

Hi I have an abstract super class Fruit and some sub-classes Apple, Orange, ...

```
abstract class Fruit {
  public abstract String getFruitName();
  public static Fruit getInstance(String fruitName) {}
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
  public String getFruitName() {return "Apple";}
}
```

And other Fruit sub-classes are the same as Apple. I want to implement the getInstance method of Fruit so that for example for the parameter "Apple" it returns an Apple object. But i don't want to use reflection and I don't want to check it by if-else or switch-case. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need a subclass? For this specific (maybe simplified?) case, fruitName could simply be a variable in a non-abstract class Fruit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Design patterns that can replace if statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31580534/design-patterns-that-can-replace-if-statements)

Comment: Actually my program is more complicated than the codes I wrote here. In my program I really can't do that @fhissen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this [factory design pattern without if-else](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/10/factory-without-if-else.html)

Comment: How can you use the techniques suggested there if you need to pass parameters into the constructors? For example, the technique that uses a `Map`. Would you have to construct the default Object and then pass your parameters into the `newInstance` method to instantiate an `Object` using parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch for fruit name if you use java 7+

Comment: a switch statement is the same as if-else. I want something else.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Factory Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html).

This is a clean approach, easy to maintain and produces readable code. Adding or removing a `Fruit` is also easy, Just remove the class and remove it from `FruitFactory` hashmap.

Create an Interface : Fruit

```
 public interface Fruit {
    void getFruitName();
 }
```

Create a Factory which returns correct Fruit according to your `value`. Instead of your `if-else` now you can just use the following :

```
  Fruit fruit = FruitFactory.getFruit(value);
  fruit.getFruitName();
```

One common way to write FilterFactory is using a `HashMap` inside it.

```
public class FilterFactory{
   static HashMap<String, Fruit> fruitMap;
   static{
       fruitMap = new HashMap<>();
       fruitMap.put("apple",new Apple());
       ...
   }
   // this function will change depending on your needs
   public Filter getFruit(int value){
       return fruitMap.get(value);
   }

}
```

Create your three(in your case) Fruits like this: (With meaningful names though)

```
public class Apple implements Fruit {

    public void getFruitName(){
      //do something
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : I see that the interface name `Fruit` clashes with your abstract class `Fruit`. You can use any name, I was just explaining the idea.